# Don't understand a line in a paper by Horibe

Tags: entropy

This question pertains to "[A Entropy view of Fibonacci Trees](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/20-2/horibe.pdf)" (1982) by Yasuichi Horibe, [Zbl 0491.94009](https://zbmath.org/0491.94009).
 Horibe defines a binary tree where a node has a left branch with probability x and a right branch with probability $1-x$. The left branch has cost 1 and the right branch has cost c. In equation (4), p. 171 of the paper, the entropy of a node per cost is provided as $$ { H(x, 1-x)} \over{x + c (1-x)} $$ Horibe states "Let $\lambda$ be the maximizing value of x. By differentiating, $\lambda$ is the unique positive root of $x^c=  1 - x$."

I am afraid I am unable to see how this is found. Can anyone on MO show me? Feeding the question to Mathematica or GPT4 produces no useful answer. Nor do I as yet follow the next sentence "The maximum value of the function is $-\log \lambda$."

Thank you,

Bill

Comment: ${ H(x, 1-x)} \over{x + c (1-x)}$ with $H(x,1-x)=-x\log x-(1-x)\log(1-x)$ has the derivative $\log[(1-x)/x^c]/(c+x-cx)^2$ which vanishes when $(1-x)/x^c=1$; at that value of $x$ a simple substitution of $c=\log(1-x)/\log x$  immediately gives $\frac{H(x, 1-x)} {x + c (1-x)}=-\log x$.